# Unable to invoke mixin module method in spec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mixins

I have the following module:

```
# lib/translator/sms_command.rb
module Translator
  module SmsCommand
    def self.included(klass)
      puts "SmsCommand initialized in #{klass}"
    end
    def alias_command(name)

    end
  end
end
```

And the following spec:

```
# spec/translator/sms_command_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

class ExampleCommand
  include Translator::SmsCommand
  alias_command :x
end

module Translator
  describe SmsCommand do
    describe "#alias_command" do
      it "registers the class with the command registry" do
        Translator::SmsCommand.command_registry.should include_key :x
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Yes #alias_command does nothing at this stage but that's because I'm in the midst of developing it.  However, when I run my spec I am seeing...

```
SmsCommand initialized in ExampleCommand
```

so the module is certainly being mixed in, however the spec barfs on the `alias_command :x` line in the `ExampleCommand` as if the `alias_command` method is never becoming available.

```
/spec/translator/sms_command_spec.rb:5:in `<class:ExampleCommand>': undefined method `alias_command' for ExampleCommand:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I could solve this problem through inheritance though I'd prefer the mixin module.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's not an include but an extend to access alias_command in your Class method

```
class ExampleCommand
  extend Translator::SmsCommand
  alias_command :x
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, I am certain you mean extend, and that is what I was missing.  I will s/exclude/extend/, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to define a class method called alias_command, don't you?
In this case you need to `extend` the class with the module, a simple include will turn the included method into an instance method!

You can do it in a widely accepted way as follows:

```
module Translator
  module SmsCommand
    def self.included(klass)
      puts "SmsCommand initialized in #{klass}"
      klass.extend ClassMethods
    end
    module ClassMethods
      def alias_command(name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This way when you include the module, it will automatically extend the target class with the class methods!